# Plot a list of functions with a corresponding list of ranges

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, functions

I have 3 functions below and I want to plot them on the same graph with different range as follows.

- Plot `f1` with `x` is in `{2, 5}` meaning that `2 ≤ x ≤ 5`
- Plot `f2` with `x` is in `{3, 8}` meaning that `3 ≤ x ≤ 8`
- Plot `f3` with `x` is in `{1, 4}` meaning that `1 ≤ x ≤ 4`

I know that this can be done by plot each of them and then use `Show` function.  
However, I'm trying to use only one `Plot` function to do it.  
  This is just an example as the number of functions and ranges are  much larger than this.

```
f1 = 2 x;
f2 = x^2;
f3 = x^3 - 2 x^2 + 5;
functions = {f1,f2,f3};
ranges = {{2, 5}, {3, 8}, {1, 4}};
Plot[functions, ranges?]
```

Comment: "However, I'm trying to use only one `Plot` function to do it." - why? Nevertheless, you can try using `ConditionalExpression[]` for this.

Comment: @J.M. I'm trying to apply this for another code so this method makes it easier for me apply it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{xmin, xmax} = MinMax[ranges];
```

#### 1. ConditionalExpression

```
conditionalfunctions = MapThread[
   ConditionalExpression[#, Between[#2] @ x] &, 
  {functions, ranges}];

Plot[conditionalfunctions, {x, xmin, xmax}]
```

[image]

You can also define `conditionalfunctions` as follows:

```
conditionalfunctions1 = MapThread[ConditionalExpression[#, #2 @ x] &] @ 
  {functions, Between /@ ranges}

conditionalfunctions2 = MapThread[ConditionalExpression] @
  {functions, Between[x, #] & /@ ranges}

conditionalfunctions3 = Thread @ 
  ConditionalExpression[functions, Between[x, #] & /@ ranges]
```

#### 2. Piecewise

```
piecewisefunctions = MapThread[Piecewise[{{#, Between[x, #2]}}, Undefined] &] @
  {functions, ranges};

Plot[piecewisefunctions, {x, xmin, xmax}]
```

[image]

#### 3. Clip

```
functionswithclippedarg = MapThread[# /. x -> Clip[x, #2, {Null, Null}] &] @
  {functions, ranges};

Plot[functionswithclippedarg, {x, xmin, xmax}]
```

[image]

Comment: Using `Between[]`: `Through[(Between /@ ranges)[x]]`, or `MapThread[ConditionalExpression[#1, Between[x, #2]] &, {functions, ranges}]`.

Comment: Thank you @J.M.; that's much cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

f1 = 2 x;
f2 = x^2;
f3 = x^3 - 2 x^2 + 5;
functions = {f1, f2, f3};
ranges = {{2, 5}, {3, 8}, {1, 4}};

Show[Plot @@@ Transpose[
   {functions, Insert[#, x, 1] & /@ ranges}],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

To use different PlotStyles

```
colors = {Red, Blue, Green};

Show[Plot[#[[1]], #[[2]], PlotStyle -> #[[3]]] & /@ Transpose[
   {functions, Insert[#, x, 1] & /@ ranges, colors}],
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]